# Popping Out of Hidden Overflow

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have items that are listed in a container with overflow-y-scroll and each item has a tooltip that needs to be displayed to the right of the list item but outside of the container.

I followed [this](https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/) article and managed to implement something similar with Tailwind. See [Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/WiLxqyikA9). The problem is that the tooltips positions are incorrect after scrolling. (I assume it's because the list item is static)

How can I make the tooltip move with the list item as it scrolls? Is there a better way to do this?

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="flex h-screen items-center justify-center">
  <div class="relative">
    <ul class="h-24 w-24 space-y-3 overflow-y-auto overflow-x-hidden rounded-md border bg-gray-100 py-2 px-4">
      <li class="group static cursor-pointer">
        Item 1
        <div class="invisible absolute z-10 group-hover:visible">
          <p class="ml-14 -mt-6 w-20 rounded-lg bg-blue-500 px-2 py-1 text-sm text-white shadow">Tooltip 1</p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="group static cursor-pointer">
        Item 2
        <div class="invisible absolute z-10 group-hover:visible">
          <p class="ml-14 -mt-6 w-20 rounded-lg bg-blue-500 px-2 py-1 text-sm text-white shadow">Tooltip 2</p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="group static cursor-pointer">
        Item 3
        <div class="invisible absolute z-10 group-hover:visible">
          <p class="ml-14 -mt-6 w-20 rounded-lg bg-blue-500 px-2 py-1 text-sm text-white shadow">Tooltip 3</p>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="group static cursor-pointer">
        Item 4
        <div class="invisible absolute z-10 group-hover:visible">
          <p class="ml-14 -mt-6 w-20 rounded-lg bg-blue-500 px-2 py-1 text-sm text-white shadow">Tooltip 4</p>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You won't be able to achieve the effect to get the tooltips out of scroll.

Comment: I think you would need a second container. An outer container without overflow hidden (just for the position relative). Inside this container you can place your element (which has overflow hidden) and the tooltip element (which will be visible because its parent doesn't have overflow hidden)